# Mahapps Custom title bar color

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Currently i am using `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />`

And this is the result:

[image]

I also found this supported colors: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents

But i cannot find the `Gray` color that i want to change into.
Any idea how to change to custom color ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set the title brush to whatever you want by setting `WindowTitleBrush="Chocolate"`

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MetroDemo.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:MetroDemo="clr-namespace:MetroDemo"
                      Title="MahApps.Metro - Demo Application"
                      WindowTitleBrush="Chocolate">
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Hope this helps!